# Vertically center element on HTML page with some content on top (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using bootstrap, which has some (minimal) content on top (basically title, subtitle, and a navigation bar). I would like to be able to center a div both horizontally and vertically. The contents of this div will be something small, like a login or search widget.

What is the recommended way to do this in Bootstrap and CSS? Of course I want it to also look "good" when opened on a phone. The content on top will be rather minimal, so on a small screen, it's unlikely the top and center will touch. This is different from other questions in this style, because I also have some content on the top. I guess I could try to follow one of those answers, and "absolutely" place the content on the top, but somehow this doesn't seem too clean. Are there better solutions?

Comment: I don't have any code to post right now, doing this from a pretty theoretical perspective as well. I basically have some content on top, but still want to center a div. What would be the recommended way to do this, in general? I don't see how posting HTML or CSS could help to make the question more clear.

Comment: The question is too broad. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kristof** Hi there. A search would have probably given you a answer on how to do this.
He is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zej5sewL/)** that will do what you want to do here.

```
.centerthis {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;  
}
```

[image]